# Can I use Agile even when the client doesn't want to participate?

Tags: agile, client-relations, requirements-management

Your client/user declares he has absolutely no intention of being available frequently throughout a project, just enough to say "I want the application to do this" and answer a few questions every month or so. Also, the idea of having to define priorities story by story makes him scream...

Yet, on all the projects you have worked on with them so far, they come up with changes all throughout development and expect these to be implemented in the final version.

Is it possible to use Agile methodologies in such a context? Can some parts of Agile still have value or do they all require frequent user involvement?

Comment: see also: [How to sell Agile development to (waterfall) clients](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215562/how-to-sell-agile-development-to-waterfall-clients)

Comment: This project is going to make everyone miserable, so just part as friends.

Comment: @JeffO: cannot part with an internal client :)

Comment: Go for bug driven development. Give the customer an hello world application. He will complain that it doesn't do what he wants. Tell him that it is a bug. Ask him what he expected. If you get a short answer, develop something small and deliver it to him. He will tell you again that this doesn't do what he wants. Tell him that it is a bug. Ask him what he expected. Develop this. ... This goes on and on until he finally sees that you cannot develop without having good specifications and input from the customer.

Comment: @user99561: Kind of what's happening already. Except we're responsible for not guessing right and all the data malformed by the missing rules is sent back to us for manual fixing. Not much fun.

Comment: @leokhorn: talk to your manager and have him talk to his manager. This way of working doesn't work. And if you can't change the job, change jobs.